# Building Skia4Delphi with PowerShell error

Tags: delphi, clang, skia, skia4delphi

I'm trying to build Skia with PowerShell, but it's returning a error...

```
> PS D:\Componentes_Delphi\skia\skia> .\sk4d-build --targets win32
> INFO: Building for Win32.
> ERROR: Unable to generate build files for Win32 target: ERROR at //gn/BUILDCONFIG.gn:161:23: Script returned non-zero exit code.
> clang_win_version = exec_script("//gn/highest_version_dir.py",
>                       ^----------
> Current dir: D:/Componentes_Delphi/skia/skia/temp/Win32/Release/
> Command: C:/Python311/python.exe D:/Componentes_Delphi/skia/skia/gn/highest_version_dir.py "C:\Program Files\LLVM/lib/clang" "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"
> Returned 1.
```

Has anyone experienced this error and know how to resolve it? I need to build for 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Solved.
Go to the main folder/gn, and edit BUILDCONFIG.GN, find the line:

```
if (host_os == "win" && clang_win != "" && clang_win_version == "")
```

And edit to the folder where you installed, like:

```
if (host_os == "win" && clang_win != "" && clang_win_version == "") {
  clang_win_version = "C:\Program Files\LLVM"
}
```